# I get broken archive when I download to the folder

Tags: bash

I get right archive when I used command:

```
    wget https://mysite/published/my_archive.tar.gz
```

I can open this archive and use.

But I create fofder for archive

```
drwxr-xr-x   folder_for_archive
```

and used command for download archive to the folder:

```
wget https://mysite/published/my_archive.tar.gz -o "./folder_for_archive/https://mysite/published/my_archive.tar.gz"
```

But archive is broken and I cannot use it.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-o` argument to `wget` doesn't do what you think it does:

> `-o logfile`
> `--output-file=logfile`
> Log all messages to `logfile`. The messages are normally reported to standard error.

Either replace `wget` by `curl` (whose `-o` option *does* do what you expect), or use `-O` (capital letter `O`) instead:

> `-O file`
> `--output-document file`
> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to `file`.

Notice the use of plural "documents": `wget` is a recursive downloader, so it might produce more than one file. But in your case, it should be fine.

See the [`wget` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for more information on both options.